# how should I pass a child object back to parent using Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a parent page where I have :

```
<CascadingValue Value="SelectedAddress">
    <CollectionAddress VendorNumber="@VendorNumber"></CollectionAddress>
</CascadingValue>
```

and the code behind this has:

```
 public AddressDTO SelectedAddress { get; set; } = new AddressDTO();
```

My child component has

```
 [CascadingParameter]
 protected AddressDTO? SelectedAddress { get; set; }
```

in the child component I set the SelectedAddress, but when I switch back to the parent The SelectedAddress is empty. Have I used this incorrectly, it's the first time I've tried to use Cascade Parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the other way around. CascadingValue is used to send data from parent to children components (usually more than one level downward). If you want to send data from child to parent use EventCallback parameters, like this:

## Parent

```
@page "/"

<CollectionAddress AddressChanged="AddressRecieved" />
@addressStree

@code {
    private string addressStree;
    public AddressDTO SelectedAddress { get; set; } = new AddressDTO()
        {
            Street = "Garden"
        };

    private async Task AddressRecieved(AddressDTO address)
    {
        addressStree = address.Street;
    }
}
```

## Child

```
<h3>Collection Address</h3>
<button @onclick="SendAddress">Change Adddress</button>

@code {
    //[CascadingParameter]
    //protected AddressDTO? SelectedAddress { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<AddressDTO> AddressChanged { get; set; }

    private async void SendAddress()
    {
        await AddressChanged.InvokeAsync(new AddressDTO { Street = "Garden" });
    }
}
```

## Dto

```
   public class AddressDTO
    {
        public string? Street { get; set; }
    }
```